# How to combine pattern_replace char_filter with synonym filter (skips synonms?)

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index where I'm trying to enforce the addition of a beginning token and ending token. (Big picture I'm trying to use match_phrase to match the entire phrase - not just a sub-phrase - of an address). I have a working char_filter that accomplishes this, but it appears to cause problems with synonym filters. This is all done on ElasticSearch 6.2.14.

Here is the smallest piece of work I have to show my issue:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "working_street_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "classic",
          "filter": [
            "street_synonyms"
          ]
        },
        "broken_street_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [
            "extraTokenAtEnds"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "classic",
          "filter": [
            "street_synonyms"
          ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "extraTokenAtEnds": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "^(.*)$",
          "replacement": "wordyword $1 wordyword"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "street_synonyms": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": [
            "south, s",
            "west, w"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here are two checks against the "_analyze" endpoint:

```
{
   "analyzer": "working_street_analyzer",
   "text":     "40 s 50 w"
}

{
   "analyzer": "broken_street_analyzer",
   "text":     "40 s 50 w"
}
```

The working_street_analyzer gives what you would expect:

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "40",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 2,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "s",
            "start_offset": 3,
            "end_offset": 4,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "south",
            "start_offset": 3,
            "end_offset": 4,
            "type": "SYNONYM",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "50",
            "start_offset": 5,
            "end_offset": 7,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 2
        },
        {
            "token": "w",
            "start_offset": 8,
            "end_offset": 9,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 3
        },
        {
            "token": "west",
            "start_offset": 8,
            "end_offset": 9,
            "type": "SYNONYM",
            "position": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

The broken_street_analyzer leaves out the synonym step. Running the _analyze with "explain": "true" shows that the synonym step is indeed ran, it just fails to find any synonyms:

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "wordyword",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 8,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "40",
            "start_offset": 8,
            "end_offset": 8,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "s",
            "start_offset": 8,
            "end_offset": 8,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 2
        },
        {
            "token": "50",
            "start_offset": 8,
            "end_offset": 8,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 3
        },
        {
            "token": "w",
            "start_offset": 8,
            "end_offset": 8,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 4
        },
        {
            "token": "wordyword",
            "start_offset": 8,
            "end_offset": 9,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `synonym` token filter relies on offsets of generated tokens, but `pattern_replace` character filter breaks the offsets: fields `start_offset` and `end_offset` for tokens `40`, `s`, `50`, `w` has the same value in `broken_street_analyzer` output.

This is known [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-6595) in Apache Lucene, which is underlying layer for Elasticsearch. Wrong offsets generated by `pattern_replace` also causing other errors in Elasticsearch, for example in results highlighting - you can read clear [explanation](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/30781#issuecomment-391276929) of why this happens.